# Как получить работающий счётчик?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Мне хотелось бы, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку в тексте менялось значение, отображая, сколько раз я нажал на кнопку. Что нужно поменять в моём коде или, может быть, он весь неправильный?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body background="Flexbox/img/fon.jpg" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 20px;">
  <script>
    var num = 0;

    function print(text) {
      document.write(text);
    }

    function oneClick(button) {
      num++;
      document.querySelector('.abc');
      abc.innerHtml("На кнопку нажато " + num + " раз!");
    }
  </script>

  <button name="button" onclick="oneClick(this)">
      Я считаю нажатия
     </button>
  <div class="abc">Нажато 0 раз</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цитата дня:

*Чтобы получить работающий счетчик, надо написать работающий счетчик.*

```js
var num = 0;

function oneClick(button) {
  document.querySelector('.abc').innerHTML = "На кнопку нажато " + ++num + " раз!";
}
```

```html
<button name="button" onclick="oneClick(this)">Я считаю нажатия</button>
<div class="abc">Нажато 0 раз</div>
```