# Где ошибка в написании счётчика?

Tags: javascript, таймер

Сделал по уроки свой таймер, но ничего не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста

```
var m = 0;
var s = 0;

function timer () {
    document.getElementById('s').innerHTML(s);
    s++;
    if (s % 1 == 60) {
        s = 0;
        m++;
    }
    else {
        continue;
    }
    if (m % 1 == 60) {
        m = 0;
        h++;
    }
    else {
        continue;
    }
    setInterval (timer, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Начнём с того, что код должен быть текстом, а не картинкой. Продолжим тем, что учитесь читать ошибки в js-консоли браузера. Закончим тем, что функции innerHtml не существует.

Comment: Добавил вместо фото код. В консоли ошибок нет. Функцию заменил на правильную (innerHTML)
Ничего не работает

Comment: Функции innerHTML тоже не существует.

Comment: откуда взят данный код?

Comment: "Где ошибка в написании счётчика?" - везде. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1118251/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba

Comment: @andreymal https://innerhtml.ru/

Comment: @НикитаПопов по указанной вами ссылке не написано ни единого слова про функцию innerHTML. Там описывается свойство innerHTML, а вот про функцию не сказано ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот держи, вот так работает.

**Запомни!**

1. innerHTML - это не метод, а свойство.
2. continue - эта директива для циклов.
3. Срочно меняй учителя (видео уроки), не знаю что за уроки ты смотришь, но автор явно пытается избавиться от конкурентов.

```js
var m = 0;
var s = 0;

function timer() {
    document.getElementById('s').innerHTML = s;
    s++;
    if (s == 60) {
        s = 0;
        m++;
    }
    else if (m == 60) {
        m = 0;
        h++;
    } 
}
setInterval (timer, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="s"></span>
```

Comment: Ещё одну логическую ошибку автора не исправили.

Comment: @andreymal Тут весь скрипт логическая ошибка, ИМХО

Comment: `s % 1` - всегда 0

Comment: @Grundy да, даже не глянул) убрал

Comment: Большое всем спасибо) Со всем разобрался, всё принял к сведению))